# Display 2 ArrayLists into a jTextArea one after another, multiple times depending on the data entered

Tags: java, arraylist

So, I'm trying to display the data stored in 2 ArrayLists into a jTextArea. The first ArrayList contains a bar's location, name, and whether is there live music and food service. The second bar contains the type of liquor and corresponding amounts of each.

I'm trying to get it to display like this:

> The (barLocation) bar is named: (barName)
>
> Live music: (true or false)
>
> Food service: (true or false)
>
> (That's the first ArrayList, followed by the second)
>
> Vodka: (amount)
>
> Whiskey: (amount)
>
> Rum: (amount)
>
> Gin: (amount)
>
> Brandy: (amount)

This works great, if I enter one bar. If I enter two or more I get a long list of the data entered in different combinations. So if I enter say two bars with their liquor amounts, I'll get like 20-30 different ones with different combinations, instead of just the two entered in the format above.

This is the code section I'm using to display the data:

```
for(int i=0; i<bars.size(); i++)
        {
            for(int j=0; j<liquors.size(); j++)
            {
                jTextAreaDisplay.append(jTextAreaDisplay.getText() 
                        + bars.get(i) + liquors.get(j) + "\n\n");
            }
        }
```

Now I know I'm doing something wrong with the for loop, and I've tried different approaches to it but I'm stuck. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

*UPDATE*

I have two classes for one bar and one for liquor. The amount for the liquor is the amount in stock, so: Vodka: 20 for example would be 20 bottles. Sorry for the misunderstanding.

Code for Classes:

```
class Bar
{
    String barLoc, barName;
    boolean music, food;

    public Bar(String l, String n, boolean m, boolean f)
    {
        this.barLoc = l;
        this.barName = n;
        this.music = m;
        this.food = f;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return "The " + barLoc + " bar is named: " + barName + "\nLive music: " 
                + music + "\nFood Service: " + food;
    } 
}

class Liquor
{
    //String[] liquor = {"Vodka", "Whiskey", "Rum", "Gin", "Brandy"};
    String vodka, whiskey, rum, gin, brandy;
    int vCount, wCount, rCount, gCount, bCount;

    public Liquor(String vodka, String whiskey, String rum, String gin, 
            String brandy, int v, int w, int r, int g, int b)
    {
        this.vodka = vodka;
        this.whiskey = whiskey;
        this.rum = rum;
        this.gin = gin;
        this.brandy = brandy;
        this.vCount = v;
        this.wCount = w;
        this.rCount = r;
        this.gCount = g;
        this.bCount = b;
    }


    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return "\nLiquor currently in stock:\n" + vodka + ": " + vCount + "\n" +
                whiskey + ": " + wCount + "\n" + rum + ": " + rCount + "\n" +
                gin + ": " + gCount + "\n" + brandy + ": " + bCount;
    }
}
```

Comment: [How to Use Tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) - basically what you're asking, just simpler

Comment: You might also consider using a `Map`, so you can map a `List` of drinks to a single bar, see [Collections Trail](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/) for more details

Comment: If you really want to use a `JTextArea`, then you could have a look at [Formatted Strings](http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/java/java_formatted_strings.html) or use a `JEditorPane` and generate a HTML based table

Comment: Would a table work on a JTextArea? I ask because it's part of the assignment.

Comment: No, you would use a `JTable` instead of a `JTextArea` because it's designed to show tabular data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get every combination because you are going to loop each liquor for every bar.

What I suggest is that you refactor your code so that the list of liquor becomes a property of a bar.

```
for(int i=0; i<bars.size(); i++)
        {
                jTextAreaDisplay.append(jTextAreaDisplay.getText() 
                        + bars.get(i).toString() + bars.get(i).getLiquor.toString() + "\n\n");

        }
```

Now you get for every bar, every liquor with price that is added for that bar.

The bar class will have the following implementation

```
public class Bar {
//your other code
private Liqour liqour; 

public Liqour getLiqour(){ return liqour;}
// your other code
}
```

When you create the Liqour for a bar, make sure you initialize it.
Liqour is not a list, but an Object with properties, so you don't need to iterate it.

Comment: Would getLiquors.size() be a different method that I create?

Comment: No because size() is a standard method for ArrayLists.

Comment: Sorry, I meant getLiquors

Comment: getLiquors() is the getter of your liquors list in your Bar class.

Comment: Okay, so I would have to make one. My liquor amounts are ints, so it would be public int getLiquors()? Sorry for all the questions. Learning as I go.

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding. I updated the code above to show you what I have.

Comment: Indeed, I refactored my code to make it work for your solution.

Comment: Okay one last thing. I've been trying to initialize Liquor in my Bar class but can't seem to get it working. I've tried by putting the strings for the 5 liquors and then by trying to call 5 new getters methods I made in my Liquor class, but it says I'm self-referencing. And my display code keeps saying symbol not found for the .getLiquors().  I'm stuck again...